# How can I add a framework into Xcode project using fastlane or command line?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, fastlane

I have an app that is dependent on a framework file that I wrote. They're independent xcode project and has their own Github repo. I want to create a fastlane to automatically add the framework to the app project and do a build whenever I commit to the app repo. Right now I have to manually add the framework into Embedded Binaries and Linked Frameworks and Libraries inside the app project. I can't find any actions in fastlane to update the project's framework section.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are wanting to manage an API framework project which you main project uses.

Fast lane (IMHO) is about building and managing built artefacts. Managing dependencies within your project is a different thing. To that end there are two options which I am aware of:

- [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) - The only option for a long time. Ruby based tool. Manages dependencies by adding builds and XCConfigs to your project. Does this by re-writing your project files. Rebuilds all dependencies when you build. My opinion - I've never been a fan. I don't like that you really need to know Ruby to use it, the way it hacks into your project and enforces it's build ideas on you.
- [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) - Newer option. OS X native tool. Updates and builds dependencies only when you tell it to. Zero impact on your project, but you have to do a little work to include the framework files. Only works with frameworks. My opinion - feels more natural that Cocoapods and the best option.